# JS, JSON - Coverter a json object to show in string format on the screen and concatenated

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm taking data that arrives via ajax and putting it in a table.

when I show the "data" attribute, it is showing on the screen (Object object), how to convert this object to show the concatenated values.

Example: day / moth / year

JSON:

```
[
  {
    tipo: "O",
    numero: "001",
    data: { year: 2019, month: 4, day: 18 },
    prazo: 0,
    documento: "4600530888",
  },
];
```

Method:

```js
function carregaAditivos() {
  $("#aditivoAbertoInformacoesTexto").html(
    '<div id="loaderMaiorDemandante"></div>'
  );
  $("#loaderMaiorDemandante").show();
  var jsonHide = $("#activeJsonHide").html();
  if (jsonHide) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "buscaTextoAditivos.action", // action to be perform
      type: "POST", //type of posting the data
      data: { linhaSelecionadaJson: jsonHide }, // data to set to Action Class
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (html) {
        var trHTML = "";
        $.each(html, function (key, value) {
          trHTML +=
            "<tr><td>" +
            value.tipo +
            "</td><td>" +
            value.numero +
            "</td><td>" +
            value.data +
            "</td><td>" +
            value.prazo +
            "</td><td>" +
            value.documento +
            "</td></tr>";
        });
        $("#records_table").append(trHTML); // em caso de erro exibe o modal com aviso
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $("#modalErro").modal("show");
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what you mean by 'to show the concatenated values', but to make it date-like replace `value.data` with `value.data.year+'-'value.data.month+'-'value.data.day`.

Or you can convert it to a Date-object and format from there.

Examples below:

```js
const dataObj = {
  tipo: "O",
  numero: "001",
  data: {
    year: 2019,
    month: 4,
    day: 18
  },
  prazo: 0,
  documento: "4600530888",
};

console.log(dataObj.data.year + '-' + dataObj.data.month + '-' + dataObj.data.day);

console.log(new Date(dataObj.data.year, dataObj.data.month - 1, dataObj.data.day).toString());
```